# How to fix 'Text is null' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, dart-null-safety

I want to create an app which has a TabBarView with two tabs. On the first Tab there is a Textfield and on the other tab there is a text widget which should display the text which you entered into Textfield
but I always get an error because text is null.( I'm new in programming with flutter)

I tried to initialize the variable in TextOutput class but it didn't work because the variable is final.

```
TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextCreatePage(), TextOutput()
      ],




class TextCreatePageState extends State<TextCreatePage> {
String textvalue;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(child: TextField(
    onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {
       textvalue = value;
       TextOutput(textvalue: textvalue,);
            });





class TextOutput extends StatelessWidget {
final String textvalue;

TextOutput({this.textvalue});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(textvalue); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 15):

So, for anyone that search this and got here, I'm using this to manage null String variables.

**1. Show Empty Text**

```dart
String nullText; //for null-safety change to: String? nullText;

//now, inside of your widget build
Text(nullText ?? '');
```

**2. Not show Text Widget**

```dart
String nullText;

//now, inside of your widget build
if(nullText != null)
 Text(nullText);
```

with null-safety

```dart
String? nullText;

//now, inside of your widget build
if(nullText != null)
 Text(nullText!);
```

Also you can show like this, but this show the **null** word

```dart
String nullText; //for null-safety change to String? nullText;

//now, inside of your widget build
Text('$nullText');
```

Live Example https://dartpad.dev/faab5bc3c2df9573c0a75a5ce3d4b4b9

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from the information your provided in your question what code causes the error, but I guess it is this line:

```
return Text(textvalue);
```

If you change it to

```
return textvalue != null ? Text(textvalue) : Container();
```

your error should go away.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the textvalue variable in Textoutput and the constructor because textvalue always is null.

Comment: Dorsn't look this way.

Comment: Hard to tell from here.

Comment: Ok, i tested some things and now I know where the error is but I don't know how to fix it. The error is probably at the constructor in the TextCreatePageState class.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't contain such a constructor.

Comment: I meant the TextOutput(textvalue: textvalue);

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Should be easy to debug though.

Comment: When I use  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => TextOutput(textvalue: textvalue2,)));   everything works ?

Answer (score 0):

Hector Aguero's answer is what I've been doing to workaround the error.

I use this everywhere:

```
Text(nullText ?? '');
```

But I wonder what's stopping Flutter team to make Text() widget support null value?

```
// This should be acceptable and simply not rendering any text
// why they don't allow this is beyond me
Text(nullText);
```